# @google-cloud/speech - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'protos.json

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use the google cloud speech to text api.

I'm using the sample google code and when i create the client object i got this error.

```
{ 
   "errno":-2,
   "syscall":"open",
   "code":"ENOENT",
   "path":"protos.json",
   "stack":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'protos.json'\n    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)\n    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)\n    at fetch (transcript-server-js/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:160:34)\n    at Root.load (/transcript-server-js/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:194:13)\n    at Root.loadSync (/transcript-server-js/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:235:17)\n    at Object.loadSync (/transcript-server-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:221:27)\n    at GrpcClient.loadFromProto /transcript-server-js/node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:165:40)\n    at GrpcClient.loadProto (/transcript-server-js/node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:199:17)\n    at new SpeechClient /transcript-server-js/lib/webpack:/src/v1/speech_client.ts:135:28)\n    at createText$ (/transcript-server-js/lib/webpack:/src/transcriptGenerator.js:50:18)"
}
```

this is the code

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const results = await storage.getBuckets();
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
```

google cloud storage api works.

can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this with `@google-cloud/firestore`. Both `@google-cloud/firestore` and `@google-cloud/speech` use the same mechanism to to load `protos.json`, so my solution should be relevant here.

This happened to me because webpack was building the `@google-cloud/firestore` package into my bundle. The `@google-cloud/firestore` package uses `__dirname` to find `protos.json`.  Since the `@google-cloud/firestore` code was in my bundle, the `__dirname` variable was set to my bundle's directory instead of to the `node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/` subdirectory that contains `protos.json`.

## Possible fix #1

Set this in your webpack config to tell webpack to set the value of `__dirname`:

```js
    node: {
      __dirname: true,
    }
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

## Possible fix #2

Update your webpack config to exclude `@google-cloud/speech` from your bundle.

One way to do this is to use the `webpack-node-externals` package to exclude all dependencies from the `node_modules` directory:

```js
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  target: 'node',
  ...
};
```

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

Comment: This save me lot of hours searching for this issue. Upvote

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Gabriel Deal.
I faced the same issue like you in firestore package. I understood why this is occurring from your explanation. Unfortunately the fixes didn't help me. So I had to take an alternate. I copied the protos.json file to the path it is searching for in my dist folder.

1. Copy **protos.json** from the node_modules to a folder (I named it **external_files**)
2. In the **webpack.config.js** copy the protos.json file from the external_files directory to the path in which it is searching (In my case it was searching in **node_modules/google-gax/protos**). Use the plugin **CopyWebpackPlugin** to do that job as shown below.

```
module.exports = {
.
.
.
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: "external_files/protos.json", to: "dist/node_modules/google-gax/protos" }
        ])
    ]
}
```